Fixed $a_p=p+1-\#E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ and $a_p \ne 0$ on an elliptic curve infinitely often for fixed curve over the rationals?
In this and this question we show that if $p=27a^2+27a+7$ is prime, then the order of the elliptic curve
$y^2=x^3+2$ modulo $p$ is either $p$ or $p+2$.

Q1 Can we unconditionally show that the order is $p$ or $p+2$
for infinitely many primes?

Let $a_4,a_6$ be integers and define the elliptic curve
$E : y^2=x^3+a_4 x + a_6$. For prime $p$ define
$a_p=p+1-\#E(\mathbb{F}_p)$
Let $a_4,a_6$ and $a_p \ne 0$ be fixed.

Q2 Are there choices of $a_4,a_6$ and $a_p \ne 0$ for which the
above definitions hold for infinitely many primes $p$?

We have $|a_p| < 2 \sqrt{p}$, so assuming it behaves
like a random number the probability is about $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{p}}$
which agrees with the quadratic density in Q1.
We know that given $a_p$ we can find $a_4,a_6$, but we want them fixed.
In case of positive answer:

Q3 Are there other constructions with $a_p=1$ (order $p$)?
This might give factoring algorithm for numbers of special form.


This question seems related to the question of extremal primes. For CM curves the exact distribution is proved by James (RIP) and Pollack, see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X16302670

Looking at the paper, it seems that they rely on the fact that such extremal primes correspond to Gaussian primes in certain narrow sectors, which is can be handled because of the strong equidistribution of roots of quadratic congruences. The problem you ask seems to be roughly equivalent to Landau's conjecture on prime values of $n^2 + k$ for a fixed integer $k$. The latter is basically impossible with current technology.

@StanleyYaoXiao Thanks. Did the paper prove that there are no other sporadic solutions except primes of certain form?

I believe there is not a single elliptic curve $E$ such that $a_p(E)$ is known to take any fixed nonzero value infinitely often.
This is (part of) the Lang-Trotter conjecture, which is wide open.
Prior work on the Lang-Trotter conjecture may be helpful to you, e.g. Lang-Trotter Conjecture for CM Elliptic Curves by Daqing Wan and Ping Xi which applies in great generality the same idea of specific values of $a_p$ occurring at prime values of quadratic polynomials.

Many thanks, I didn't expect this to be open.
